# How to use/add dynamic radio button

Tags: javascript

i got a button, and 4 text field, when i click the button,4 radio button will be create, and the value in 4 text field will be my radio button value,but how to do that?

Comment: Please first try to explain it as clear as possible. From your qs, what you have tried (assumed) that you have created forms with button and raidio buttons in designer mode. Right?

Comment: i wish to generate a dynamic radio button at html by button clicked, and the position of my radio button is under my button

Comment: my question is button clicked to add 4 radio button, and get value from 4 different textbox
radio button1 = A+textbox.Text;
radio button2 = B+textbox.Text;
radio button3 = C+textbox.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternate solution, also using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/tweJE/1/